# PRISM - Xamarin UI Test (Dependency Injection)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

Sorry for being a newbie when it comes to UI Test. Would it be possible to use Dependency injection at UITest in order for me to test the actual value of a certain result, e.g a prompt using a DI for prism it is `(PageDIalogService)`? If yes, what kind of implementation should I follow? or do I have to mock it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For UI test you need the full app working . so it does not matter if you Use DI or not . 
the  main thing that you need is to set the Automation Id set to the controls that you need to test . 
Because what happens is that the UI Test framework when a page is ready it will check the elements using the AutomationId and perform some actions. Without caring about how the app works inside.  It will only care about the UI elements that show and the values they hold.